# App running on emulator but not working on real device

Tags: java, android

Android app running completely on android emulator but when I installed it in real device then it is installed and launched perfectly but when I clicked on `RecyclerView` element then it stopped automatically without any error.

here is the log cat:

```
10-07 23:59:26.109 2257-13892/? I/AudioController: internalShutdown
10-07 23:59:26.116 2257-2257/? I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
10-07 23:59:26.116 2257-2257/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
10-07 23:59:26.116 2257-13891/? I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
10-07 23:59:31.121 2257-2257/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
10-07 23:59:31.121 2257-2257/? I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
10-07 23:59:31.125 2257-13897/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
10-07 23:59:31.125 2257-10935/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@d5819da
10-07 23:59:31.127 1411-13900/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa8603140 ready to run
10-07 23:59:31.132 1411-1411/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
10-07 23:59:31.132 1411-1411/? D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xa8f9cef0, size=4194304)
   0: 0xa8f9cf30 | 0x00000000 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   1: 0xa8f9cf50 | 0x000200E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   2: 0xa8a7f1e0 | 0x000401C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   3: 0xa8a7f190 | 0x000602A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   4: 0xa8a7f450 | 0x00080380 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   5: 0xa8a7f650 | 0x000A0460 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   6: 0xa8689090 | 0x000C0540 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   7: 0xa8a7f900 | 0x000E0620 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   8: 0xa8a7fa50 | 0x00100700 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   9: 0xa8a7fbb0 | 0x001207E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  10: 0xa8a7f780 | 0x001408C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  11: 0xa8a7fe90 | 0x001609A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  12: 0xa8a7ffc0 | 0x00180A80 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  13: 0xa68fd060 | 0x001A0B60 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  14: 0xa8689190 | 0x001C0C40 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  15: 0xa68fd330 | 0x001E0D20 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  16: 0xa68fd4c0 | 0x00200E00 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  17: 0xa68fd6a0 | 0x00220EE0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  18: 0xa68fd840 | 0x00240FC0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
  19: 0xa68fdae0 | 0x002610A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 

    10-07 23:59:31.132 1411-1411/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
    10-07 23:59:31.133 2257-10935/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
    10-07 23:59:31.137 2257-10935/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
    10-07 23:59:31.137 2257-10935/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
    10-07 23:59:31.137 2257-10935/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@d5819da
    10-07 23:59:31.137 2257-10935/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
    10-07 23:59:31.137 2257-2257/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
    10-07 23:59:31.152 2257-10935/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@d5819da
    10-07 23:59:31.152 2257-13897/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
    10-07 23:59:31.153 2257-13897/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
    10-07 23:59:31.153 2257-2555/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
    10-07 23:59:31.153 2257-13897/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
    10-07 23:59:31.153 2257-13897/? I/AudioController: internalShutdown
    10-07 23:59:31.154 2257-2257/? I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
    10-07 23:59:31.154 2257-2257/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
    10-07 23:59:31.155 2257-13896/? I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker 
    cancelled
```

Answer (score -1):

Look, this error can be anything. Your analysis needs to get better, try searching some information on this topics:

- used android target version
- used support packages and when they apply
- used android audio package and version
- android phone details

hope this helps you

Comment: @Ravi Shankar show us the code for RecyclerView and you might mention the real device information specs